# RxJava Observable.create wrapping observable subscriptions

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, rx-java2

I used Observable.create so I could notify the subscriber when certain data was available. I am a little uncertain of subscribing to observables inside of my create method. Are these nested subscriptions going to give me any sort of issue? I'm not completely familiar with creating observables using Observable.create so I wanted to make sure I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary or misusing it. Thank you in advance!

```
abstract class NetworkResource<ApiType, DbType> constructor(private val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider) {

    abstract fun fetchFromApi(): Single<ApiType>
    abstract fun fetchFromDb(): Observable<Optional<DbType>>
    abstract fun saveToDb(apiType: ApiType?)
    abstract fun shouldFetchFromApi(cache: DbType?): Boolean

    fun fetch(): Observable<Optional<DbType>>  {
        return Observable.create<Optional<DbType>> {
            val subscriber = it

            fetchFromDb()
                    .subscribe({
                        subscriber.onNext(it)

                        if(shouldFetchFromApi(it.get())) {
                            fetchFromApi()
                                    .observeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                                    .map {
                                        saveToDb(it)
                                        it
                                    }
                                    .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
                                    .flatMapObservable {
                                        fetchFromDb()
                                    }
                                    .subscribe({
                                        subscriber.onNext(it)
                                        subscriber.onComplete()
                                    })
                        }
                        else {
                            subscriber.onComplete()
                        }
                    })

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will cause an issues.

First, it is not idiomatic to nest `Observable` like this, one of the strengths of Reactive approach, is composing `Observables`, and thus have single clean stream. with this way, you are breaking the chain, and the immediate result is intertwined code which is harder to read, and more code to wire up the notification events, basically it is like wrapping async callback methods with `Observable`.
here as you have already reactive components you can simply compose them instead of treating them with callback approach.

Second, as a result of breaking the chain, the most sever and immediate one - unsubscribing the outer `Observable` will not affect automatically the inner `Observable`.   same goes for trying to add `subscribeOn()` and with different scenario where backpressure is important it's also apply.

an composing alternative might be something like this:

```
fun fetch2(): Observable<Optional<DbType>> {
        return fetchFromDb()
                .flatMap {
                    if (shouldFetchFromApi(it.get())) {
                        fetchFromApi()
                                .observeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                                .doOnSuccess { saveToDb(it) }
                                .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
                                .flatMapObservable {
                                    fetchFromDb()
                                }

                    } else {
                        Observable.empty()
                    }
                }
    }
```

if from some reason, you want in any case the first `fetchFromDb()` result to be emitted separately, you can also do it using `publish()` with selector:

```
 fun fetch2(): Observable<Optional<DbType>> {
    return fetchFromDb()
            .publish {
                Observable.merge(it,
                        it.flatMap {
                            if (shouldFetchFromApi(it.get())) {
                                fetchFromApi()
                                        .observeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                                        .doOnSuccess { saveToDb(it) }
                                        .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
                                        .flatMapObservable {
                                            fetchFromDb()
                                        }

                            } else {
                                Observable.empty()
                            }
                        })
            }

}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Could you give an example of what you mean by using publish() ?

Comment: example added with publish selector, with this way, we'll have both the original result of fetchFromDb() and the resulted flatMapped fetchFromDb

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.